# How can I access the hashes in an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have an array of hashes titled `entities`

Here is a look at the array:

```
  p "entities"
  y entities
  p "entities[0]"
  y entities[0]
  p "entities[1]"
  y entities[1]
  p "entities[2]"
  y entities[2]
```

Output:

```
"entities"
--- |
 --- 
 - :text: Berlin
   :links: 
   - http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin
 - :text: Jan Karski
   :links: 
   - http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jan_Karski
 - :text: God
   :links: 
   - http://dbpedia.org/resource/God
"entities[0]"
--- "-"
"entities[1]"
--- "-"
"entities[2]"
--- "-"
```

I can't figure out how to access the individual hashes. Should something be coming up when I do `p entities[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `entities.kind_of? String` true? It looks like entities is actually a YAML string. Hence, entities[0/1/2] are the first three dashes of the YAML.

Comment: That was it, I forgot to add serialize :entities to the model. Thanks for your help, I will mark as correct

Answer (score 1):

Did that copy right?  the output, pasted into a irb session comes out as a single string, not an array:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > YAML::parse("--- |
ruby-1.9.2-p0">  --- 
ruby-1.9.2-p0">  - :text: Berlin
ruby-1.9.2-p0">    :links: 
ruby-1.9.2-p0">    - http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin
ruby-1.9.2-p0">  - :text: Jan Karski
ruby-1.9.2-p0">    :links: 
ruby-1.9.2-p0">    - http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jan_Karski
ruby-1.9.2-p0">  - :text: God
ruby-1.9.2-p0">    :links: 
ruby-1.9.2-p0">    - http://dbpedia.org/resource/God
ruby-1.9.2-p0"> ").value
 => "--- \n- :text: Berlin\n  :links: \n  - http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin\n- :text: Jan Karski\n  :links: \n  - http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jan_Karski\n- :text: God\n  :links: \n  - http://dbpedia.org/resource/God\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `entitles` may be not really array of hashes.
Look this:

```
irb(main):001:0> e = [{:a=>1,:b=>2},{:c=>3,:d=>4}]
irb(main):002:0> p e
[{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:c=>3, :d=>4}]
```

Try `entitles.class` and `entitles[0].class`